# What does "eq" in the jquery .eq() method stand for?

Tags: jquery

example:

```
$("td:eq(2)").css("color", "red"); or
$('td').eq(2).css("color", "red");
```

I want to know what the abbreviation "eq" stands for, I am not asking what the .eq() method does, which can be found [here](http://api.jquery.com/eq/).

Regarding the importance of the question: I myself find it easier to learn a language, when I know what certain abbreviations really stand for. And I also sometimes "read" my written code aloud using "real" words.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I have always assumed that `.eq()` is short for "equals." [Many (perhaps](http://www.merriam-webster.com/browse/dictionary/e/eponymy.htm) [even most) common](http://www.merriam-webster.com/browse/dictionary/e/equation%20of%20continuity.htm) [English-language words](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:English_words_prefixed_with_equi-) that start with "eq" have [the *equi-* prefix](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/equi-#Prefix), rooted in the Latin word for "equals."

Comment: exactly, and i would say $('td').eq(2) is read : select element 'td' at index position 'equals' 2

Comment: I also always "read" it as "equals", but semantically, without the word "index", that somehow doesn't make sense. Definition-wise neither [here](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) nor [here](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) does the word "equals" appear in the description

Comment: @drkthng jQuery object is an array-like object, `eq` selects an element at a specific index in jQuery collection so _equals_ makes sense.

Comment: @undefined having a look at the other index related methods and "extensions" like lt(),gt() or slice(), that also take indexes without semantically expressing this fact, the "equals" assumption seems to make sense a lot. I will mark this answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 66):

`eq()` makes sense if you know it's part of a related set of selectors (from the JQuery docs):

> The index-related selectors (**`:eq()`**, **`:lt()`**, **`:gt()`**, **`:even`**, **`:odd`**) filter
>   the set of elements that have matched the expressions that precede
>   them.

When lined up next to `lt` (less than), and `gt` (greater than), it's clear that it means equals, specifically "*index* equals *n*".

Comment: I especially agree with your reasoning in the last line!

Comment: A really bad name in my opinion. I failed to memorize it and I always need to look up the list of all methods to re-find it. At least I know now where it came from. I hope this will help memorizing it. This should be the accepted answer. The currently accepted one isn't wrong, but it didn't explain to me why one would name it like that.

Comment: in a sane world those would be "at", "before", and "after"

Answer (score 5):

I think of it as **e**lement **q**ueue.

Answer (score 1):

i always think `eq` is short of `sequence` :)

Comment: Then why `eq` instead of `seq` or `se`?

Comment: i don't know the why, it's just easier for me to think that way :)