# How to select nth item inside select element in cypress

Tags: javascript, select, cypress

say I have the HTML:

```html
<select name="subject" data-testid="contact-us-subject-field">
  <option value="What is this regarding?">What is this regarding?</option>
  <option value="Partnerships">Partnerships</option>
  <option value="Careers">Careers</option>
  <option value="Press">Press</option>
  <option value="Other">Other</option>
</select>
```

Selecting an option with a known value, such as 'Careers' is as easy as:

```js
cy.get('[data-testid="contact-us-subject-field"]').select('Careers');
```

How do I select the nth option in this field, *regardless* of its value?

Answer (score 141):

### Update

As pointed out by @dpstree in the comments, this doesn't answer the original question. Please see more recent answers for a complete solution.

### Original

By using [eq](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/eq.html#Usage)

```js
cy.get('tbody>tr').eq(0)    // Yield first 'tr' in 'tbody'
cy.get('ul>li').eq(4)       // Yield fifth 'li' in 'ul'
```

Comment: Is `eq` an abbreviation? What does it mean?

Comment: As mentioned by the documentation page I linked, the term comes from jQuery. So you may be interested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15059207/what-does-eq-in-the-jquery-eq-method-stand-for)

Comment: This doesn't select anything. It does demonstrate the .eq() syntax that is needed as part of the solution, but misses the important context of needing to manipulate the select. See  Robert or Miguel's solution below.

Comment: My word, you're right, I must have read the question too quickly. Will edit to point this out.

Comment: Also, the eq()in Cypress simply doesn't work. I've tried it just about anywhere in my angular 8 application, where there are rows of elements with some element or other having the same ID in each row. If there are two buttons with the same ID, Cypress will ALLWAYS click the first one, whether I use eq(0) or eq(1). At the same time, it DOES try to honor the index, since it won't accept eq(2) when there are only two. But it doesn't work. At all.

Comment: Just remember that if you save this selection to a variable, it won't work. 

const mySelection = cy.get('tbody>tr') ;  mySelection.eq(0); mySelection.eq(1) --> the will be no second element. 

You need to call a selection function again

Comment: why do i feel like there should an `nth()` command!?

Answer (score 55):

In the particular context of *selecting* the nth `option`, this may be appropriate:

```
cy.get('select[name=subject] > option')
  .eq(3)
  .then(element => cy.get('select[name=subject]').select(element.val()))
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, please note that soon there might be an easier solution https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/757. Small suggestion for @Robert to use cy.wrap() + parents() to not duplicate the selector: `.eq(2).then(($el) => cy.wrap($el).parent('select').select($el.val()))`.

Answer (score 28):

Based on solution from [Miguel Rueda](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10451645/miguel-rueda), but using `prevSubject` option:

```js
Cypress.Commands.add(
  'selectNth',
  { prevSubject: 'element' },
  (subject, pos) => {
    cy.wrap(subject)
      .children('option')
      .eq(pos)
      .then(e => {
        cy.wrap(subject).select(e.val())
      })
  }
)
```

## Usage:

```js
cy.get('[name=assignedTo]').selectNth(2)
```

## Explanation:

- Using `children('option')` and `.eq(pos)` traverse children of select to specific element.
- Call `select` method with value of selected element.

Answer (score 23):

You can now select an option by `index` within the `.select(index)` command:

```js
cy.get('select').select(0)        // selects by index (yields first option) ie "What is this regarding?"
cy.get('select').select([0, 1])   // select an array of indexes
```

This should be easy now with the release of cypress [v8.5.0](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/releases/tag/v8.5.0). See [documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/select#Index) for more.

Comment: And what if I have a dynamic selectbox and want to select last option and don't know its name or value?

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem and solved it by creating a custom cypress command. No as pretty as I would like, but it did the job.

```
Cypress.Commands.add("selectNth", (select, pos) => {
  cy.get(`${select} option +option`)
    .eq(pos)
    .then( e => {
       cy.get(select)
         .select(e.val())
    })
})
```

then I used in the test as such

```
    cy.viewport(375, 667)
      .selectNth("customSelector", 3)
```

The `option +option` part was the only way I could find to get the full list of options inside a select and it's currently the bit of code i'm trying to work arround although it works fine.

Answer (score 8):

since the working answers are using then anyways, eq or something fancier is redundant with array indexing...

```
// to click on the 1st button
cy.get('button').then($elements => {cy.wrap($elements[0]).click();});
// to click on the 4th tr
cy.get('tr').then($elements => {cy.wrap($elements[3]).click();}); 
// to click on the last div:
cy.get('div').then($elements => {cy.wrap($elements[$elements.length - 1]).click();});
```

Comment: finally, one that works.  in my case: `cy.wrap($recordings[0]).findByRole('button', { name: 'Remove' }).click({ force: true })`

Answer (score 3):

Let's assume you wanna select 2nd option, you can do that simply by this

```
cy.get("select option").eq(2)
```

just keep in mind that `cy.get()` works like jquery's `$()`.

Comment: Index number starts on 0. If you want the 2nd element, then you do this: cy.get("select option").eq(1)

Answer (score 2):

Find dropdown using ID or Class -

```js
cy.get('#ID').contains("dowpdown placeholder or name").click();
```

After Click dropdown result dropdown element will popup, find that result ID or Class using inspect element, Then -

```js
cy.get('#result-ID').children().first().click();
```

This will click on the first element of the dropdown.

Answer (score 1):

You can also rely on the [:nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) css pseudo-class:

```
cy.get("[data-testid="contact-us-subject-field"] option:nth-child(2)").click();
```

It's probably less flexible than using the cypress constructs but it is nice and clean. (And doesn't make me crawl through the cypress docs)

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking a value to select then you cannot use `.eq()`, you need to use `.contains()`
`.eq()` is only for numbers(indexes)

Example:  `cy.get(dropdownOptions).contains(some_value).click()`

Answer (score 0):

If you look for the nth option in the select dropdown, for example, in case the data is dynamically changed and you want to select the nth one, whatever the content may be, you can use this syntax:

**App**

```
<select name="mySelect">
  <option value="option_1">option 1</option>
  <option value="option_2">option 2</option>
  ...
  <option value="option_n">option n</option>
  ...
</select>
```

**Spec**

```
cy.get("[name='mySelect'] option:nth-of-type(n)")
.invoke("text")
.then((text) => {
  cy.get("[name='mySelect']").select(text);
});
```

And note that `n` is the order of the option that you want to select. **The count start from 1.**

Answer (score -1):

Capture all the elements in the drop-down using a selector. Get the length. Use `math.random()` to randomly get a number. Select the option at the index.

```
cy.get("ul > li").as("options")
cy
.get("@options")
.its('length')
.then(len => Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(len)))
.then((index) => {
cy.get("@options").eq(index).click()
})
```